# Is a analytical solution of integral of product of error function and other power law function possible?

Tags: integration, error-function

I am trying to get a analytical solution for a integral,

$$\int{x^a \text{erf}(bx)dx}\text{, when }a<1$$

usually, if $a$ is an integer there are solution which are

$$\int{r\cdot\text{erf}(br) dr}=\frac{1}{4}\Biggl(\frac{2r\cdot\exp(-b^2r^2)}{b\sqrt \pi}+\left(2r^2-\frac{1}{b^2}\right)\text{erf}(br)\biggr)+\text{constant}$$

$$\int{r^2 \text{erf}(br) dr}=\frac{1}{3}\Biggl(\frac{(b^2r^2+1)\exp(-b^2r^2)}{b^3\sqrt \pi}+r^3\text{erf}(br)\biggr)+\text{constant}$$

and so on.

is there a way to solve when $a$ is fraction, for example $a=2/3$?

Comment: I see a gamma function appearing in [wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+x%5E(2%2F3)+erf(bx)+dx).

Comment: Thanks snulty. Seems like I can work with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By integrating by parts,$\newcommand{error}{\operatorname{erf}}$

\begin{align}\int x^a\error(bx)~{\rm d}x&=\frac{x^{a+1}}{a+1}\error(bx)-\frac{2b}{(a+1)\sqrt\pi}\int x^{a+1}e^{(bx)^2}~{\rm d}x\\&=\frac{x^{a+1}}{a+1}\error(bx)+\frac{(-1)^{(a+1)/2}}{(a+1)b^{a+1}\sqrt\pi}\int u^{(a+1)/2}e^{-u}~{\rm d}x\\&=\frac{x^{a+1}}{a+1}\error(bx)+\frac{(-1)^{(a+1)/2}}{(a+1)b^{a+1}\sqrt\pi}\Gamma\left(\frac{a+1}2,-(bx)^2\right)+C\end{align}

where $\Gamma(s,x)$ is the [incomplete Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function) and $u=-(bx)^2$.

Comment: Is the incomplete gamma function appearing because of the change of variables?

Comment: if we modify the terms a little, lets say $$\int(bx+a)^cerf(x)dx$$, can there be any solution without Taylor expansion of the $(bx+a)^c$ term?

Comment: @snulty Yes, that is why it appears. For your second problem, yes, you could apply Taylor/binomial expansion, though I wouldn't call the result "closed form".